# fusion tables sql DELETE more than one rows in just one access

Tags: sql-delete, google-fusion-tables, delete-row, app-inventor

I'm working in an app with **App Inventor 2** and fusion tables. The users will store some information in the tables and I want them to have the option of deleting what ever they want, in fact it's good for the app, it goes better.

The problem is that I only know how to delete one row, and I want to give the option of deleting all old information (for example 50 rows). It's not useful to do it one by one. Does anyone know a way to do it at once?

I've tried `DELETE FROM xxxxxx WHERE ROWID='XXX' OR ...` It doesn't work because `OR` is not supported. `DELETE FROM xxxxx WHERE ROWID IN (........)` doesn't work neither. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 04/2017**: you can now delete several rows like this

```
DELETE FROM <tableid> WHERE <your where condition>
```

It seems to be, Google forgot to update the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#deleteRow)...
[image]

---

Unfortunately this is a limitation of the fusiontable SQL language, see again the [SQL Reference Documentation of the Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#deleteRow).

You can only delete the complete table like this

```
DELETE FROM <tableid>
```

or delete several rows one by one,
 see also [How to delete one or more rows from a  Fusiontable](https://puravidaapps.com/fusiondelete.php)

**EDIT:**
If you are interested in a feature to be able to update/delete several rows, then you might want to star [issue 417](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=417). To *star* an issue means, to click onto the star in the upper left corner of the issue to vote for it and to get an email in case there are news

A workaround to delete multiple rows is to create a view, [see also this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/google-fusion-tables/E8H74n6pbBg/btPj-ubBSkcJ). However unfortunately this is not possible in App Inventor.

My suggestion for you is to use a **MySQL** database instead. To use a MySQL database from within App Inventor, see also my [App Inventor - MySQL interface](https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php).

Comment: I'm already doing like that, deleting one by one, but it takes so long to delete more than 10 rows... If there is no more options..

Comment: see my updated answer. Btw: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: now you also can send DELETE statements like this `DELETE FROM <tableid> WHERE <your where condition>`. I updated my answer...